# How do I get roblox studio on a Chromebook?

Tags: roblox

I have seen Youtube videos of people having roblox studio on their chromebook, but I have tried to install it and it didn't work.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you cannot natively install Roblox onto a Chromebook, due to the lack of Linux support, but you can still run it using an emulator such as **Grapejuice**. Here's how to do that.

1. Make sure the Chromebook is set up to use Linux applications.
2. Use this command in the terminal for 32-bit support: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
3. Next, install WINE, a Windows application emulator using this command: `sudo apt install -y wine git python3-pip pkg-config libcairo2-dev libdbus-1-dev gtk-update-icon-cache desktop-file-utils xdg-utils libgirepository1.0-dev gir1.2-gtk-3.0`
4. Next, get the files for Grapejuice with this command, which allows Roblox Studio to run on Linux: `git clone https://gitlab.com/brinkervii/grapejuice.git`
5. Finally, run these two commands to install Roblox Studio and Grapejuice: `cd grapejuice` and lastly, `python3 ./install.py`

Although this will function, **some areas of the application will not work as well (or at all) as they would on a native machine.** Here is the official project information on Grapejuice [here](https://pypi.org/project/grapejuice/).